# why i get segment error when i print 2-D array which is delivery by the "main" function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

why I get segment error when I print 2-D array which is delivery by the "main" function?There is a condition that the array must be delivery as int** 。how can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display_matrix(int** matrix, int row, int column) {
    printf("%d\n", matrix[1][2]);
}

void main() {
    int m[3][4] = {
        {1, 3, 5, 7},
        {10, 11, 16, 20},
        {23, 30, 34, 60}
    };
    display_matrix((int**) m, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: Beginners need to compile with maximum warnings and then pay attention to them. This isn't valid C and won't compile cleanly. You shouldn't have gotten as far as running the code.

Comment: Anyway, simply change your function to `void display_matrix(int row, int column, int matrix[row][column])`.

Comment: @Lundin How do you think about the condition "There is a condition that the array must be delivery as int** 。"?

Comment: It's nonsense. The most important rule of engineering is to always question if the specification makes sense. That's what makes engineers different from the animals/code monkeys.

Comment: This question is coming from my training in the leetcode platform, the question define the function  prototype。[question](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

An array declared like

```
int m[3][4] = {
    {1, 3, 5, 7},
    {10, 11, 16, 20},
    {23, 30, 34, 60}
};
```

used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[4]`.

So the types `int ( * )[4]` and the type `int **` are not compatible. Dereferencing the pointer of the type `int **` for the declared array above you will get the value `1` that is not a valid address. So the function invokes undefined behavior.

Thus a function that accepts such an array as an argument should be declared like

```
void display_matrix( int ( *matrix )[4], size_t rows );
```

and the function can be called like

```
display_matrix( m, 3 );
```

Or if your compiler supports variable length arrays then the function can be declared like

```
void display_matrix( size_t rows, size_t cols, int ( *matrix )[cols] );
```

and the function can be called like

```
display_matrix( 3, 4, m );
```

Such a declaration of a function

```
void display_matrix(int** matrix, int row, int column);
```

usually is used when you allocated arrays dynamically like

```
int **m = malloc( 3 * sizeof( int * ) );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
    m[i] = malloc( 4 * sizeof( int ) );
}

//... initialization of the arrays and


display_matrix( m, 3, 4 );
```

So either define the array dynamically or use one more array declared like

```
int * a[3] = { m[0], m[1], m[2] };
```

and pass this array instead of the array `m` to your function.

In this case the array `a` used as an argument expression in this call

```
display_matrix( a, 3, 4 );
```

will be implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int **`.

Comment: How do you think about the condition "There is a condition that the array must be delivery as int** 。"?

Comment: Is "int ( * )[4]" means a pointer type that points to an int array with four elements?

Comment: @江上轻烟 Yes you are write. If for example you have an array declared like int a[4]; then you can write int *p1 = a;  In this case teh pointer a points to the first element of the array. But if you will write int ( *p2 )[4] = &a; then the pointer p2 will point to the whole array. That is dereferencing the pointer like *p2 you will get the array.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting Segmentation Fault because you are passing an array of integers to where an array of pointers is expected.

You have to prepare an array of `int*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display_matrix(int** matrix, int row, int column) {
    printf("%d\n", matrix[1][2]);
}

int main(void) {
    int m[3][4] = {
        {1, 3, 5, 7},
        {10, 11, 16, 20},
        {23, 30, 34, 60}
    };
    int* m_ptr[3] = {m[0], m[1], m[2]};
    display_matrix(m_ptr, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: There's no apparent reason for creating such a strange pointer array. All it achieves is to make the code less efficient and harder to read. Instead rewrite the function so that it makes sense.

Comment: @Lundin - I think the function prototype is not negotiable for this problem per OP:  _"...the array must be delivery as int**"_.

Comment: @ryyker But that function API strongly suggests that whoever wrote the function didn't know what they were doing. So this is definitely where you should start questioning what they were thinking when they designed the function.